# java -version does not change

Tags: java, macos, java-8, java-home

I am having trouble changing the version of java running on my Mac running Big Sur 11.2 with zsh. I want to set Java 1.8 as my default, so I used the following commands to set JAVA_HOME:

```
$ unset JAVA_HOME
$ export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v "1.8.0_281")
$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_281.jdk/Contents/Home
```

However, when I ran `java -version` I kept getting JDK 15 as the current default. I then removed jdk15 from the JavaVirtualMachines directory and repeated the setting of JAVA_HOME, but I continue to observe the same result.

Comment: Which `java` executable is called depends upon the `PATH` variable, not the `JAVA_HOME` variable.

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz ... and that is `/usr/bin/java` on all macs, which is just a wrapper that goes elsewhere. Messing with PATH is not how you change that sort of thing.

Comment: @rzwitserloot .. which is probably a symbolic link to the real executable.

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz Indeed it is, and that file cannot be overwritten or changed in any way, not even with `sudo`. The only way to do it, is to disable system security which is quite the ordeal and extremely not recommended - that's absolutely not the way to change mac defaults. I know it's weird - there is no point trying to assist with this question if you are not familiar with how macs work.

Comment: @rzwitserloot you mean “`PATH` is *supposed* to contain `/usr/bin/java` (and no other java)”. You don’t really know, what it contains on the OP’s machine. On the other hand, we *do know* that something in the OP’s environment doesn’t work as it is supposed to do.

Comment: @Holger yes, PATH variable shenanigans can explain why OP is observing what they are observing. Messing with PATH is not, however, the right way to change which java version is run when you just type `java` on the command line. At best we can give advise on how to undo the messup there. Piotr and co are strongly suggesting that OP should add the java they prefer to the front of their path, and that is very bad advice.

Answer (score 4):

Other answers so far are talking about $PATH. This is a red herring; `/usr/bin/java` is on the path, it should remain on the path, and it is a light wrapper that goes to your actual, selected java installation.

The recommended strategy is to just use tools to solve this problem for you, such as [jEnv](https://www.jenv.be). Install it via brew if you have it, otherwise, follow instructions on the site.

If you don't want to go the established route of using jEnv, the not-recommended route is, indeed, to mess with JAVA_HOME. `/usr/bin/java` will use whatever default rolls out of `/usr/libexec/java_home`. java_home will defer to what JAVA_HOME (the environment variable) says; only if it is unset will it give you its own default, which is generally the latest installed and very hard to change otherwise.

The fact that it isn't working for you suggests you have some different kind of shell, or that java version isn't listed by `java_home`, or you've messed with PATH in some very drastic ways (would involve removing security control from your mac disk and such), so I doubt that's it - doublecheck what you've done so far? Which mac version are you on?

An example from a mac:

```
/usr/libexec/java_home
> /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-14.jdk/Contents/Home
java -version
> openjdk version "14.0.1" 2020-04-14

/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8
> /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home

/usr/libexec/java_home
> /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home
java -version
> openjdk version "1.8.0_252"
```

Answer (score 0):

You should ensure that the right java version path come first in your PATH environmental variable

Comment: `/usr/bin/java` is on the path, and that is a wrapper that goes to an actual java installed elsewhere. Messing with the PATH is not how you change this stuff.

Answer (score 0):

**TLDR:**

1. `echo $PATH` and copy it's value
2. `export PATH=""`
3. `export PATH="/path/from/step1/with/java/removed"`

**End TLDR**

Had the same issue with Big Sur when I tried to switch to `java 11`, despite everything pointing to correct values, `java -version` always returned `java 8`

```
$ java -version
openjdk version "1.8.0_292"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (AdoptOpenJDK)(build 1.8.0_292-b10)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (AdoptOpenJDK)(build 25.292-b10, mixed mode)

$ whereis java             
/usr/bin/java

$ /usr/bin/java -version
openjdk version "11.0.11" 2021-04-20
OpenJDK Runtime Environment AdoptOpenJDK-11.0.11+9 (build 11.0.11+9)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM AdoptOpenJDK-11.0.11+9 (build 11.0.11+9, mixed mode)

$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-11.jdk/Contents/Home

$ java -version         
openjdk version "1.8.0_292"
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (AdoptOpenJDK)(build 1.8.0_292-b10)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (AdoptOpenJDK)(build 25.292-b10, mixed mode)

$ which java
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
```

To fix I had to remove Java SDK from `PATH` using steps in TLDR above

```
$ echo $PATH
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/munki:/opt/X11/bin:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-11.jdk/Contents/Home/bin:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home/bin:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-11.jdk/Contents/Home/bin

$ export PATH=""
direnv: error can't find bash: exec: "bash": executable file not found in $PATH                                                                             

$ export PATH="/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/munki:/opt/X11/bin"

$ echo $PATH    
/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/munki:/opt/X11/bin
```

Afterwards

```
$ java -version 
openjdk version "11.0.11" 2021-04-20
OpenJDK Runtime Environment AdoptOpenJDK-11.0.11+9 (build 11.0.11+9)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM AdoptOpenJDK-11.0.11+9 (build 11.0.11+9, mixed mode)
```